# Hypothesis testing Z-test:Where does the normal curve come from?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem, p-value

When performing a hypothesis testing z-test we can in the end determine the p-value using a standard normal curve after determine the z-score. Is the standard normal curve derived from my sample, that is using central limit theorem and then standardize the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard normal curve is independent of your sample. Given a certain p-value, we can calculate the confidence interval for your estimation. You can look up central limit theorem MIT on youtube for 2 good examples (50 min video).